# toString returning same String for every object of a particular class?

Tags: java, string, object, static, return

Are there any future problems if my toString returns String static reference:-

```
public static String example = "any problem";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return example;
    }
```

Comment: You do realize that you'll always get the same output when you try to print the `toString()` of an instance of this class. That way you'll not be able to differentiate between the instances(atleast when trying to print them).

Comment: No. It is probably not very useful though.

Comment: To get a same string why to you want to call an object function, you can simply hardcode that in your code

Comment: @Henry Are you saying my Password class has limited commercial value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Strings are immutable no caller can change the underlying String reference any other caller has; therefore it is safe. However, it's not very useful since that value is shared by all instances of the class - why not just use `return this.getClass().getName();` if that's what you want?

Comment: Even I don't know why , my friend's development head asked him to do so, and since toString distiguished object of same I class , I thought he may end up with mess later but now it's ok..thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem, however toString method is used to represent the object state, not the class state so you may want to reconsider your toString implementation. Also, your String is public and can be modified by anyone.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's perfectly fine. I think for clarity that I would use the following to emphasize that it's static and should not be changed (replacing `ClassName` with your actual class name):

```
public static final String example = "any problem";

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ClassName.example;
}
```

Otherwise, though it's fine. I'm not entirely sure why you *would* want to return the same `toString()` for each instance; ideally, it should uniquely represent different instances of a class, if it makes sense for your case.

Minor sidenote: I removed the `// TODO` comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you will have trouble modifying the variable at a later time the answer is no. You are able to modify a Static Variable.

Comment: No @Chris Ogle it was regarding distinguishing object..thanks anyway.